# .Net regex find only the text between two string tokens that appear multiple times

Tags: .net, regex, string

Here is the string I am searching:

```
 ABC=#XXX#result string (1)#XXX#this is #text# in the middle #XXX#result string (2)#XXX#
```

Here is the result I would like to retrieve using the .Net Regex class:

```
result string (1)
result string (2)
```

The closest I have come is with this:

```
Regex.Matches(srchstrg, "#XXX#" + "(.+)" + "#XXX#");
```

But it doesn't quite have the result I want.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the center group lazy, or it will try to match as much as possible. Try

```
#XXX#(.+?)#XXX#
```

This will make it so it only matches as little as possible, so it'll get both strings you want.

Answer (score 0):

If `#` is not in the result text, then search using the negative set which says match what is *not* `^` in the negation set. `[^#]+` says match until a `#` is encountered.

```
#XXX#([^#]+)#XXX#
```

That is a lot cleaner than trying to minimize a greedy operation.